# Differential equation of falling object

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose a mass is dropped from a height of 300 m, whose speed obeys the differential equation $$\frac {dv}{dt} = 9.8 - \frac v5 . \tag{1}$$

We want to find the time of and speed at impact with the ground. Since it is dropped (from rest) we can assume the initial condition is $v(0) = 0$. Moreover since it is dropped from a height of $300$ m we have the second initial condition $x(0) = 300$ where $x(t)$ is the position function i.e. the antiderivative of $v(t)$.

Solving $(1)$ together with $v(0) = 0$ yields $$ v(t) = 49(1 - e^{-t/5})\ .$$

Integration results in $$ x(t) = 49(t + 5e^{-t/5}) + C$$

With $x(0) = 300$ we can determine $C = 55$. Thus $$x(t) = 49(t + 5e^{-t/5}) + 55 \ .$$

We are interested of the time of impact i.e. when $x(t)$ is equal to zero, since $x(0) = 300$. But this produces the equation 
$$x(t) = 49(t + 5e^{-t/5}) + 55 = 0 \ , $$

which turns out to be insoluble. So forum, what is at fault here and why is it $x(0) = 300$? It turns out everything will work out if one sets the initial condition to be $x(0) = 0$ but I don't really agree or am convinced by the inital condition being exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that the sign of your velocity and position are not consistent in the way you do it. If you have a look at your formula for $v(t)$, then you see immediately that $v(t)>0$ for all $t>0$. Hence $x(t)$ will *increase* over time, i.e. starting at 300 you will *never* reach 0. In fact, the absolute heights are not important. You can choose any height $h$ you want to determine $C$ and then the moment of impact is given by the equation $x(t)=h+300$ (and *not* $h-300$).

Perhaps this sounds unusual since the mass falls down and not up. If you want to change this, you have to modify your differential equation.

Comment: Great answer, the sign of $v$ determines the increase/decrease of $x$ and in our case, starting at 300, it cannot reach 0. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome!