# Differential equation of falling object (cont.)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Continuing from [Differential equation of falling object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914782/differential-equation-of-falling-object): I got an answer in the previous thread for my main question but I subsequently devised another approach which also is, unknown to me why that is the case, failing.

An object starting at rest is dropped from an height of 300 m; its speed obeys $$ v(t) = 49(1 - e^{-t/5}) \ .$$

In particular we have $v(0) = 0 $. 
We want to determine when it hits the ground. Say it takes $\tau$ seconds and under these seconds it travels a distance of 300 m. So for $0 \leq t \leq \tau$ the change in distance is $300$. Thus we can write $$\Delta x = 300 = \int_0^\tau v(t) \, dt = \int_0^\tau 49(1 - e^{-t/5} ) \, dt = 49(5e^{-\tau/5} + \tau - 5) \ . $$

But this implies $\tau \approx -6.2$ seconds, so clearly something is wrong here. I do not see what exactly it is. We could try $\Delta x = -300$ but that results in a insoluble equation. What went wrong?

EDIT: Apparently I did not find the positive solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is correct, but the solution for positive τ is τ ≈ 10.51 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cfrac {300}{49}\approx 6$ it looks to me as though $\tau \approx 11$ ignoring also the exponential which is not too large (order of $1$)

__

To get a better estimate take $\tau =10$ in the exponential, so that $5e^{-2}\approx \cfrac 5{2.7^2}\approx 0.7$ and $\cfrac {300}{49}\approx 6.1$ which gives $10.4$ with very little work, with the exponential being overestimated a little, so the estimate will be a little on the low side.